# What is the right approach to initialize the Model's data inside of the mvc layout page and bind it to the dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-layout

Currently, I'm doing the following logic:

I have a Layout page where I need to display a Kendo.DropDown list.

I have created a Model:

public class CultureModel
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }

```
public List<string> AvailableCultures { get; set; }

public CultureModel()
{
    PopulateCulture();
}

private void PopulateCulture()
{
    CultureModel cm = new CultureModel();
    cm.AvailableCultures = new List<string>();
    cm.AvailableCultures.Add("en-US");
    cm.AvailableCultures.Add("de-DE");
    cm.AvailableCultures.Add("es-ES");
}
```

}

And in my Layout I define the model: `@model CultureModel`

Then, I'm trying to render DisplayTemplate to show the dropdown:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AvailableCultures, "_CultureSelector")
```

And my template is:

```
@model List<string>

<label for="culture">Choose culture:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("culture")
)
```

Is that correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about your usecase by having a dropdown in the layout file, it would be  fine to create your kendo dropdown with the following code directly in the layout file:

```
@{
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("Cultures")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "en-US",
              Value = "1"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "de-DE",
              Value = "2"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "es-ES",
              Value = "3"
          }
      })
   )
}
```

Perhaps use a partialview to render the code in the layout for better code organizing and readability:
     `@Html.Partial("_CultureSelector")`

I found the code on the telerik site: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist

Comment: It looks like a good option, but I think the DisplayTemplate will be reusable